# How to convert a csv to shift_jis using in linux

Tags: linux

I have done this command

```
iconv -f us-ascii -t SHIFT_JIS qpr_specify_item_def.csv > specify_item_def.csv
```

but is getting an exception

```
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 548
```

Comment: You can look at what you have at position 548. We can't.

Comment: Its a japnese sequence